# How can I plot arrays of different shapes?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, plot

I have three different csv files with two columns each. The first column is the Epoch and the second column is Intensity. For the first two files, the length is the same - 60. But the third file, has a length of 1030. I want to plot all these csv files on the same plot. And I have tried to do so. Epoch columns for file 1 and file 2 have time stamps at an interval of 1.5 minutes, but for file 3, the time stamps are random. I had considered creating offsets for the time stamps but I am not sure how that would work.

Since the files are large I am including snippets of the data.

```
epoch_1 = np.array(['2020-07-11T02:00:30.000Z', '2020-07-11T02:01:30.000Z','2020-07-11T02:02:30.000Z', '2020-07-11T02:03:30.000Z','2020-07-11T02:04:30.000Z', '2020-07-11T02:05:30.000Z','2020-07-11T02:06:30.000Z', '2020-07-11T02:07:30.000Z','2020-07-11T02:08:30.000Z', '2020-07-11T02:09:30.000Z','2020-07-11T02:10:30.000Z', '2020-07-11T02:11:30.000Z','2020-07-11T02:12:30.000Z', '2020-07-11T02:13:30.000Z','2020-07-11T02:14:30.000Z', '2020-07-11T02:15:30.000Z','2020-07-11T02:16:30.000Z', '2020-07-11T02:17:30.000Z','2020-07-11T02:18:30.000Z', '2020-07-11T02:19:30.000Z'])

intensity_1 = np.array([1.03587, 1.03187, 1.03561, 1.02893, 1.04659, 1.03633, 1.0481,1.04156, 1.02164, 1.02741, 1.02675, 1.03651, 1.03713, 1.0252,1.02853, 1.0378 , 1.04374, 1.01427, 1.0387 , 1.03389])

epoch_2 = np.array(['2020-07-11T02:00:30.000Z', '2020-07-11T02:01:30.000Z','2020-07-11T02:02:30.000Z', '2020-07-11T02:03:30.000Z','2020-07-11T02:04:30.000Z', '2020-07-11T02:05:30.000Z','2020-07-11T02:06:30.000Z', '2020-07-11T02:07:30.000Z','2020-07-11T02:08:30.000Z', '2020-07-11T02:09:30.000Z','2020-07-11T02:10:30.000Z', '2020-07-11T02:11:30.000Z','2020-07-11T02:12:30.000Z', '2020-07-11T02:13:30.000Z','2020-07-11T02:14:30.000Z', '2020-07-11T02:15:30.000Z','2020-07-11T02:16:30.000Z', '2020-07-11T02:17:30.000Z','2020-07-11T02:18:30.000Z', '2020-07-11T02:19:30.000Z'])

intensity_2 = np.array([1.02097 , 1.06292 , 1.08389 , 0.958054, 1.10487, 1.08389,1.02097 , 1.04195 , 0.979027, 1.08389 , 1.04195 , 1.04195, 1.04195 , 0.937081, 1.25168 , 1.06292 , 1.04195 , 1.04195 ,1.08389,1.08389])

epoch_3 = np.array(['2020-07-11T02:00:02.676555136Z', '2020-07-11T02:00:06.171916544Z','2020-07-11T02:00:09.667033856Z', '2020-07-11T02:00:13.162395264Z','2020-07-11T02:00:16.657756672Z', '2020-07-11T02:00:20.152873856Z','2020-07-11T02:00:23.648235392Z', '2020-07-11T02:00:27.143352576Z','2020-07-11T02:00:30.638713984Z', '2020-07-11T02:00:34.134075392Z','2020-07-11T02:00:37.629192576Z', '2020-07-11T02:00:41.124554112Z','2020-07-11T02:00:44.619915520Z', '2020-07-11T02:00:48.115032704Z','2020-07-11T02:00:51.610394112Z', '2020-07-11T02:00:55.105511424Z','2020-07-11T02:00:58.600872832Z', '2020-07-11T02:01:02.096234240Z','2020-07-11T02:01:05.591351552Z', '2020-07-11T02:01:09.086712832Z',])

intensity_3 = np.array([4.08873e-20, 4.32314e-20, 4.89188e-20, 4.94567e-20, 3.44891e-20,4.07720e-20, 3.95423e-20, 5.02253e-20, 4.24629e-20, 3.67563e-20,4.22323e-20, 3.39319e-20, 4.10026e-20, 4.07720e-20, 4.57677e-20,4.40384e-20, 3.34515e-20, 4.10026e-20, 4.38847e-20, 4.36157e-20])
```

The last array needs to be converted into log and is done using --

```
intensity_3 = np.log(intensity_3/1e-21)/np.max(np.log(intensity_3/1e-21))
```

When I plot it using the following --

```
plt.plot(epoch_1, intensity_1)
plt.plot(epoch_2, intensity_2)
plt.plot(epoch_3, intensity_3)
plt.yscale('log')
```

it looks like --

[image]

Is there anyway to create offsets for the dates? I would like for the intensity_3 data to lie on the same range as the other two.

Comment: I would not modify the green data, I would simply plot it on a [twiny axes](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.twiny.html).

Answer (score 0):

You have to postprocess your measurements and normalize them if you want to show them on the same sized xaxis:

One basic way to do this would be to rescale your xaxis onto the same size. In the example below i rescale the xaxis into a size of 100 and the number of points between these ranges is adapted to the number of values (`len(epoch_1)`)  in your epoch.

This would rescale all your epoches, independent from their amount of measurements, onto the same sized xaxis.

```
xaxe1= np.linspace(0,100,len(epoch_1))
xaxe2= np.linspace(0,100,len(epoch_2))
xaxe3= np.linspace(0,100,len(epoch_3))

#epoch_3=epoch_3-(epoch_3-epoch_2)

plt.plot(xaxe1, intensity_1)
plt.plot(xaxe2, intensity_2)
plt.plot(xaxe3, intensity_3)
plt.yscale('log')
plt.show()
```

[image]

In this case resized would mean that your timedelta (`endtime_ofmeasures - starttime_ofmeasures`) gets fitted into a range of 0-100.

If you have different timedeltas between your eproches then the solution above wont be good because some epoches will be compressed and others will be extended.

In that case you would have to use something similar to this.

`np.linspace(min(epoch1),max(epoch1),len(epoch_1))`
`np.linspace(min(epoch2),max(epoch2),len(epoch_2))`
`np.linspace(min(epoch3),max(epoch3),len(epoch_3))`

Here it would probably also make sense to turn your epoch into dtype=datetime64. Like this numpy can make find a min() and a max in the epoches easier. Here is an example for epoch1:

```
epoch_1 = np.array(['2020-07-11T02 ..... 30.000Z'], dtype="datetime64")
```

Comment: Thank you! but in the original data the shapes are different. for ease of communication i've included the arrays of same sizes but in the original data epoch_3 and intensity_3 have a length of 1030. so i cant plot epoch_2 and intensity 3.

Comment: i edited my post. maybe you get an idea how you could solve it. The thing is that you need to normalize your values. Maybe this gives you an rough idea how to do it.

Comment: I understand a bit more. But I still have a doubt, if the data that's supposed to go on the X axis is time, what does it mean if it's resized? I'm not sure how to correctly display the x axis then

Comment: see edited answer above. maybe it helps. ofc you need to adapt the solution above to your needs.